# I am not gaining body weight and I am now 23 years old

Tags: weight-gain, muscle-gain, bodyweight

I've done a lot workout and also tried all possible ways still I'm not gaining weight. My height is 5.7" and weight is 50Kg only. And I'm 23 years old now. Me and my friend joined the gym and did workout for 6 months of time. We both are of same sized when joined but now he is 66Kg heavier and I'm still at 50 Kg. Even I eat more than him. Still unable to gain weight. One important thing is that I'm strictly vegetarian. Please suggest me what should I do. I also reported this problem to my family doctor and he suggested me some reports, and that all reports were normal. I don't understand what should I do. Please suggest me the best way,

Comment: What does your diet consist of? What exercise do you do at the gym?

Comment: Vegetables. You need to eat a LOT more to get the same amount of protein, fats, and carbs as from eating meats.

Comment: @MarkGabriel vegetarians eat a lot more than just vegetables.

Comment: If your friend has gained 66 Kg in six months, there are some serious issues here...

Comment: @SeanDuggan I think he means that he is 66kg now, which would be 16kg heavier. 35 lbs in 6 months is still massive gains, though.

Comment: Yes, but my friend eats everything. I mean eggs, meat etc. He takes 2 eggs with milk. We both did the same workout, but the visible changes are only in his body. And I'm 3 years old than him :(

Answer (score 3):

**1. Check your protein intake**

Weigh how much you eat of everything and use nutrition facts tables or internet information (like at [self.com](http://nutritiondata.self.com/)) to count how many grams of protein you get per day. You might want to borrow or buy a precision scale, with precision down to the gram.

You should aim for at least 1.5grams per kilo of weight per day, thus, for a 50kg person, 75 grams of proteins per day. Try to get your proteins from varied sources so that you get all essential proteins, the one your body can't produce, and a variety of aminoacids.

If you are low on protein with your current diet, you should consider protein-dense food like beans, lentils, chickpeas, soybeans, tofu...

If you can't stuff any more protein into your mouth from food alone, you may supplement. By "strict vegetarian" I hear you won't take whey (milk-based) or albumin (egg-based). Controversy aside, you might consider soy protein or look for other isolated vegan proteins.

**2. Check your calories**

Eating a lot of proteins but not enough calories altogether is no good. You body will recycle the proteins into carbs. When measuring your food for proteins, count the total calories too. Be sure you get 3000+ kcal per day.

**3. Try pre- and post-training snacks**

If you eat nothing before weightlifting, your muscle cells might get starved during training, compromising it. Eat a snack before. Preferably something with a low glicemic index so you get a nice flux of energy for a longer time. Then eat a big protein-rich, high glicemic index snack or meal after training. This should replenish your energy and give you an insulin spike designed to stuff your muscle cells as much as possible with both glucose and proteins.

**4. Check your sleep**

The third pillar of bodybuilding, after training and diet, is rest. Sleep as much as you can. 8hr per night is a good goal, but it might depend on your personal physiology. Sleep is fundamental for muscle gain and too often overlooked.

**5. Don't overdo cardio**

Doing a lot of cardio is a common mistake. You may skip it altogether if your goal is pure muscle gain. You may do a dirty bulking phase now and start thinking of a cut phase when you've reached your weigh goal, [or not](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/dirty-bulking-why-you-need-to-know-the-dirty-truth.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nowadays I've started running upto 4Kms and also doing some stretching exercises. Should i continue with it or should i do weight lifting and other muscle training exercises?

Comment: If you want to gain lean mass, lift weights and drop the cardio for now. Unless you really enjoy it and it's your motivator for showing up at the gym. It shouldn't. If you goal is more lean mass, feel satisfied when you've had a good weight lifting session. Enjoy the muscle fever as a sign of good training.